# ASP.NEt MVC VB no editable Fields lose Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

i have a huge Problem. After i gave my Html.EditorFor the htmlAttribute "disabled" (So i cant edit that field) i lose the Data (Data is filled with NULL), that was in this Field, after i save it. If i remove this, everything works fine.
No Errors appear and the Function works fine...
I really dont know why this happens...

Many Thanks!

View :

```
Using (Html.BeginForm())
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Dezernate</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.ID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Rechner, New With { .class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Rechner, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.disabled = "disabled"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Rechner)
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Dezernat, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
         <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Dezernat, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.disabled = "disabled"}}) <-- See
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Dezernat, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
         </div>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Scan, New With { .class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select id="scan" name="Scan">
                    <option selected value= false></option>
                    <option value=true>Installiert</option>
                    <option value=false>Nicht Installiert</option>
                </select>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Scan)
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
End Using
```

Controller :

```
 <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function Edit(<Bind(Include:="ID,Dezernat,Rechner,Scan,Photoshop")> ByVal dezernate As Dezernate) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.Entry(dezernate).State = EntityState.Modified
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If
        Return View(dezernate)
    End Function
```

Comment: Forms only post back the name/value pairs of their successful controls. Disabled controls are not successful controls (make them readonly instead)

Comment: Disabled controls (with `disabled = true`) never posted back to controller - just use `readonly = readonly` to post non-editable controls instead.

Comment: That helped... idk why i  didnt think of that. Thanks!